# HttpClient.getParams() deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache-httpclient-4.3. I would analyze a http request, in particular the query string parameters, but

```
@Deprecated
public HttpParams getParams()
Deprecated. (4.3) use constructor parameters of configuration API provided by HttpClient
```

I am not sure to understand what this means. I should use the constructor parameters of some configuration API (what's that? HostConfiguration is no more available as class). But during the construction phase I directly pass the query parameters through the url:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://example.com/?var1=value1&var2=value2");
```

I can't find a way to read back the parameters (*var1, var2*) from my *request* object without using deprecated methods, which should be simple as to get attributes from an object.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but as I said, I don't understand what the information means. I don't know how to retrieve the "constructor parameters of configuration API".

By your comment I understand this is a really simple operation, could you provide a short example on where to start?

Comment: Well, it is simple when you follow the Javadoc, yes; however you seem to be mixing things -- `HttpParams` _does not_ return any contents of the query string.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use an [URIBuilder](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.4/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) object

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("http://example.com/");
builder.setParameter("var1", "value1").setParameter("var2", "value2");

HttpGet request = new HttpGet(builder.build());

// get back the url parameters   
List<NameValuePair> params = builder.getQueryParams();
```

I think you are a bit confused about the `getParams()` method from the client or HttpMethod, `getParams()` does not return the URL parameters or something like that, returns the client parameteres like connection timeout, proxy, cookies... etc

Before 4.3.2 you could set the parameters to the client using the `getParams()` method (deprecated now), after 4.3.2 you can set the request params via the `RequestConfig` class using a `Builder`

```
Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
requestConfigBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000).setMaxRedirects(1);
```

and then set to the `HttpMethod` only (not to client like before)

```
request.setConfig(requestConfigBuilder.build());
```

**Update:**

If you want to get the URI parameters from an `HttpGet` or `HttPost` request object you can use the `URIBuilder` in the same way

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://example.com/?var=1&var=2");

URIBuilder newBuilder = new URIBuilder(request.getURI());
List<NameValuePair> params = newBuilder.getQueryParams();
```

Comment: Thank you @vzamanillo. This clarifies a lot. So the parameters are accessible only because you create them. Do you think this is a good approach?
I mean, let's suppose I receive a HttpGet object, just the HttpGet object, from a third part: in this case I can't access in easy way the query string parameters?

Comment: You can access to the URI parameters using an URIBuilder, please read the updated post.

Comment: The URIBuilder link is broken.