# What is the new method to make a client server request from previously used depricated class DefaultHttpclient,HttpGet ,HttpResponse?

Tags: java, android

In my project i want to request a server , so i use a client named DefaultHttpclient. For connecting client and server i use HttpGet ,HttpResponse also.But this class are depricated .

```
 class RequestThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //super.run();
        DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getReq=new HttpGet(REQ_URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse resp=client.execute(getReq);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

What are used instead of it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient.getParams() deprecated. What should I use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038957/httpclient-getparams-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: The link you share doesn't solve my problem. I want to change this depricated version and want to use newer version . How can i do this ?

Comment: HttpURLConnection is the accepted class