# How to set HTTP Protocol version when using Spring restTemplate.exchange?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Framework **restTemplate.exchange** method to perform **HTTPS GET** call and map the response object to the entity class like below.
The target server gives success response only when I send the request with HTTP protocol version 1.1 (**HTTP1.1**). I verified it using the curl command. RestTemplate uses HTTP1.2 by default. I'm using Apache HTTP Client v4.3 here in which **httpClient.getParams** is deprecated. So I'm not able to set the HTTP protocol version using getParams method. Is there any other way to set the http protocol version as **HTTP1.1** when using restTemplate.exchange method?

```
@Autowired
CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new 
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}

public ResponseEntity<Foo> getResponse(){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate
       .exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Foo.class);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Q: Any idea why HTTP 1.1 template works, but HTTP 1.2 doesn't???  Is it because `httpClient.getParams` is deprecated?  Would this be a solution to your problem: [HttpClient.getParams() deprecated. What should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041217/3135317)

Comment: @FoggyDay I'm passing Basic Authentication credentials as part of this HTTPS GET call. I noticed that the Authorization credentials are stripped off when using HTTP 1.2 at target server end and observed 401 Unauthorized errors in the logs. But I received success response for the same request when I forced from client (using curl) to use HTTP 1.1.

Comment: "Forcing Spring to use HTTP 1.1" sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/652145).  I'd be much more interested in the root cause (HTTP 401 because authorization credentials are getting stripped) and solving that problem.  Is this applicable: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4716

Comment: @FoggyDay It may be an XY problem _and_ outside the poster's control.

Comment: I was facing some issue with Rest Template so I used  `OkHttp Client` Next you can configure rest template with Okhttp client like this https://github.com/zeagord/SpringCustomHttpClient

Comment: I am not sure how. But i had the same issue but i was using rest template with default http client. When i forced it to use Apache http client (just for logging purpose), issue got resolved on its own.